# In Rstudio, I can't save a pie as html resulting from plotly

Tags: r, character-encoding, rstudio, pandoc, plotly

I am using plotly in R for construct interactive graphs...
But I am having problems to export as html in rstudio (in my pc - in some others there is no problem)

For example, when I do something like this

```
id<- rep(1:10) 
df<- as.data.frame(id)
df$response<- c(rep("sim", 3), rep("nao", 2), rep("sim", 1), rep("sim", 4))
tab<- as.data.frame(freq(df$response))
tab<- tab[-3,]

library(plotly)

plot_ly(tab, labels = row.names(tab), values = Percentual, type = "pie") %>%
     layout(title = enc2utf8("Sim/Nao response") )
```

[image]

In this case, there isn't problem to export as html("Save as Web Page..." in the export option in Rstudio). But, the problem arises when I change the "nao" response by "não"

```
df$response<- c(rep("sim", 3), rep("não", 2), rep("sim", 1), rep("sim", 4))

Encoding(df$response)
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "latin1"  "latin1"  "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[9] "unknown" "unknown"
all(stri_enc_isutf8(df$response))
  > F
df$response <- stri_encode(df$response, "", "UTF-8")
all(stri_enc_isutf8(df$response))
   > T
Encoding(df$response)
[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown" "UTF-8"   "UTF-8"   "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"
[9] "unknown" "unknown"
....
tab<- as.data.frame(freq(df$response))
tab<- tab[-3,]

plot_ly(tab, labels = row.names(tab), values = Percentual, type = "pie") %>%
  layout(title = enc2utf8("Sim/Não response") )
```

[image]

With the following error, when I try to export as html( saving a empty file)

```
pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\xe3':Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
In addition: Warning message: 
running command 
'"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" 
"C:\Users\miguel.orrillo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqCrv6d\viewhtml32f478a42aff\inde x.html" --from markdown_strict --output "C:\testes\teste2.html" --self-contained  --template   "C:\Users\miguel.orrillo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpqCrv6d\file32f45bef54ef.html"'     had status 1
```

[image]

I am using windows 7 and Rstudio Version 0.99.447 – © 2009-2015

Comment: I think you need to ensure that character strings are in UTF-8 encoding.  Try this `Encoding(df$response ) <- "UTF-8"`. Let me know if this works - I don't have your computer or data to test.

Comment: It doesn't work. I edited some results about the encondings...

Comment: Try htmlwidgets::saveWidget?

Comment: saveWidget(as.widget(p), file="m2.html")
pandoc.exe: Cannot decode byte '\xf3': Data.Text.Internal.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 1
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS C:\PNADC2016\m2.html --from markdown_strict --output C:\PNADC2016\m2.html --self-contained --template C:\Users\miguel.orrillo\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpwDZlyv\file46705397168d.html' had status 1